# How to mock AWS SNS-SQS outages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, spring-boot-actuator, event-driven, event-driven-design

In our application, we have a event driven architecture where we communicate between de-coupled systems using AWS SNS-SQS. We publish event to SNS and receive via SQS.
We recently faced outage with SNS during some hours due to AWS issue. We had a backup of events to replay events.

We have added code to send alert if communication with SNS or SQS fails, like logging exception when we try to send message to AWS SNS.
Is there any way we can mock a failure of AWS service. I know localstack is used to replicate scenarios in local environment, but how do we replicate failure where a particular service has outage.

Also how do we handle such outages?

Comment: [AWS Fault Injection Simulator | Fully-Managed Fault Injection Service | Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/fis/) but I don't think it does those services.

Comment: I think we need to create separate environment for this, and cannot try it out in a staging environment. But yes, It does not cover sns and sqs as of now.